# combine grep with the watch and netstat command

Tags: grep, watch

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)
2.6.18-164.el5

I am trying to use the watch command combined with the netstat to see the 2 programs using certain ports.

However, with the command I using below doesn't work for both words:

```
watch -n1 "netstat -upnlt | grep gateway\|MultiMedia"
```

Is this the correct way to grep for both program names.

If I use one its ok, but both together doesn't work.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For the grep you need:

```
"grep gateway\|MultiMedia"
```

So perhaps try:

```
watch -n1 'netstat -upnlt | grep "gateway\|MultiMedia"'
```

Comment: and how to list the output?

Answer (score 1):

There's also the new way of doing things... grep -E is nice and portable (Or egrep, which is simply quick for grep -E on linux&bsd) so you don't have to escape the quote. From the man pages:

`-E      Interpret pattern as an extended regular expression (i.e. force
             grep to behave as egrep).`

So...

`watch "netstat -upnlt | grep -E 'gateway|multimedia'"`

or

`watch "netstat -upnlt | egrep 'gateway|multimedia'"`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem monitoring an ssh connection.

```
> netstat -tulpan|grep ssh
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.52:58072     192.168.2.1:22          ESTABLISHED 31447/ssh
```

However `watch -n 1 'netstat -tulpan|grep ssh'` shows no output (apart from message from watch).
If I change it to `watch -n 1 'netstat -tulpan|grep ":22"'` I get the required output line. It seems as if the -p option is ignored when netstat is run through watch. Strange.